# Is it mutar to kill a gentile to save one's life?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, murder

I know that it is forbidden to kill another Jew to save your own life, as it says in [Sanhedrin 74](http://www.come-and-hear.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_74.html). Does this law extend to a gentile?